# Weird spaces after \magstepN

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

Consider **example1**:

```
hello%
world
\bye
```

In **example2** a space is added between `o` and `w`, in comparison with example 1:

```
hello%
\magnification\magstep0
world
\bye
```

(It seems that space (which appeared from `^M`), is not gobbled after a macro argument. Is it a general rule?)

In **example3** a small kern is added between `o` and `w`, in comparison with example1:

```
hello%
\magnification\magstep0%
world
\bye
```

Why those unwanted spaces appear and how to remove them?

Comment: `\magstep0` does not mean no space.  The natural size of a font is its \magstep0 size.

Comment: @R.Schumacher: `0` is just an example. Try, e.g., `\magstep1` and you will see.

Comment: Of course, it makes no sense setting `\mag` in horizontal mode, does it?

Comment: @egreg: I occasionally stumbled upon it. I just thought that spaces are *always* gobbled after a number.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Not after a number: after a constant required by the syntax. As Heiko explains, at the point `0` is absorbed it is not yet a constant required by the syntax. If you say `\magnification1200`, then a space would be gobbled.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`\magstep` is a macro, which takes one argument. Thus `\magstep0` or `\magstep{0}` uses `0` as argument. A space afterwards remains, because it is not touched by `\magstep0` at all.

There is an implicit kern between `ow`. They are moved a little together. Example 3 breaks this implicit kerning, because it inserts unexpandable stuff (assignment of `\magnification`) inbetween. Therefore this should be avoided in the middle of words.

Comment: Are spaces removed at the beginning of a document? (if we begin a document with `\magnification=\magstepN` a space is introduced)

Comment: @IgorLiferenko An assignment does not introduce a space.

Comment: `\magnification=\magstepN` is the same as `\magnification\magstepN`, isn't it? I mean the space which I'm talking about in the question: the one which appeared from `^M`. Anyway, I found the explanation: *TeXbook*, page 112, second paragraph.

Comment: @IgorLiferenko Spaces in vertical mode are ignored.